# Node JS Trireme include module

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, apigee, bridge

I'm running Node JS with https://github.com/apigee/trireme from Java, inside the JVM. I have a directory that looks as following:

```
node/
-test_file.js
-test_somemodule.js
-somemodule/
-somemodule/index.js
-somemodule/...
```

I have no problem running the test_file.js using this code:

```
@Test
public void shouldRunTestScript() {
    try {
        NodeEnvironment env = new NodeEnvironment();
        // Pass in the script file name, a File pointing to the actual script, and an Object[] containg "argv"
        NodeScript script = env.createScript("my-test-script.js",
                new File(Settings.getInstance().getNodeDir() + "/my-test-script.js"), null);
        // Wait for the script to complete
        ScriptStatus status = script.execute().get();
        // Check the exit code
        assertTrue("Exit code was not 77.", status.getExitCode() == 77);
    } catch (NodeException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TriremeTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        fail("Trireme triggered an exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In the file test_somemodule.js I include the index.js.

```
require('somemodule/index.js');
```

When I try to run that file, it can't find the file in the require. 
I have no knowledge about Node JS, so I'm not familiar with the module loading. I already tried setting NODE_PATH, only to get

> Error: Cannot find module 'request'

It seems like I can't obtain the NODE_PATH from Trireme, and if I overwrite it, Trireme fails to run. I'm out of ideas on how I could get an Node JS module loaded in Trimere. Any help appreciated.

**Edit**: I changed the require to ('./somemodule/index.js'), which works. So setting the NODE_PATH would have done the job too. I just found out the error came from an missing dependency.

```
  "dependencies": {
"request": "^2.49.0",
"tough-cookie": "^0.12.1"
 },
```

I figured out the best way to deal with it is installing Node JS + npm, and invoking npm install some_module in the node/ folder. It automatically downloads some_module and all of its dependencies into my node/ folder. 
No more require errors.

Comment: That edit actually answers your question, doesn't it? :P

Comment: @E_net4 Yep, it does :D Would you recommend creating an answer or just leaving the question as it is?

Comment: Do **not** leave the question as it is. Move the answer part to an answer of your own.

Comment: @E_net4 That's what I initially used to do, but I was discouraged by having to wait before I can accept my own answers. I think the amount of time you have to wait increases with each answer you accept from yourself. That made me think that it was a bad thing to answer your own questions.

Comment: Waiting is natural and should not be a discouragement. On the other hand, leaving a question apparently unanswered is much worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not specify that the file was in the working directory.

```
require('./somemodule/index.js');
```

instead of

```
require('somemodule/index.js');
```

did the job. Another possiblity is to set the NODE_PATH environment variable to the node/ folder, so you can require without `./`.

I also figured out that the best way to obtain modules is by installing them with npm instead of downloading them from git, because the latter does not download any dependencies.